# Need help in display date from MySQL

Tags: datetime, laravel-5

I have been searching for full day, but could not find a relevant post to a simple problem.
I am unable to display a Datetime data from Mysql table to an html5 datetime-local input element.
Help will be highly appreciated.

Html element is:

```
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');echo 'T';echo date ('H');echo ':';echo date('i');?>" required="required">
```

My Controller code is:

```
$invoice = Purchase::find($id)->toArray();
$items = Purchase::find($id)->items->toArray();
return response()->json(array('invoice'=>$invoice,'items'=>$items));
```

And Ajax code is:

```
$('#date').val(data.invoice['date'].toString('Y-m-dTH:i'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download `moment.js` from https://momentjs.com and include it in `<head>`, then change this line

`$('#date').val(data.invoice['date'].toString('Y-m-dTH:i'));`

to

`$('#date').val(moment(data.invoice.date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm"));`

Comment: Still the date is not displaying.  
My input element is :
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');echo 'T';echo date ('H');echo ':';echo date('i');?>" required="required">
and current date is displayed like this :
24-May-2019 06:54 PM

Comment: sorry for the mistake, I've updated the code, please try again